Issue with MAX(RunDateTime) in Union Query for Retrieving Most Recent Report Runtime
I have a query that I’m trying to use to retrieve the most recent runtime of reports launched from our app. The query is designed to fetch the report name, the most recent runtime (RunDateTime), and various other columns such as the app's last access date and status.
There are three ways reports can be launched:

From the App launcher, which updates the LastAccessDate column in the App table.
From the Report launcher, where I need to pull the MAX(RunDateTime) from the ReportLog table.
A third method, which only updates the ReportLog and not the app’s LastAccessDate.

To address these, I’m using a UNION to combine the results from both the ReportSchedule and ReportLog tables, and then retrieve the most recent RunDateTime from either source. However, I'm encountering an issue: for some records, the MAX(RunDateTime) is not returning the most recent date.
My understanding is that this may be due to how the UNION works. There could be records with the same report name across both tables, and it may be incorrectly comparing a more recent RunDateTime from one table with an older one from the other.
For example, it may be the case that the max LastRun from ReportScheduler is the only max I'm seeing rather than a max coming from the ReportLog.
DECLARE @ThresholdDate DATETIME;
SET @ThresholdDate = '2021-09-18';

SELECT
    reportinfo.ReportName,
    MAX(reportinfo.lastrun) AS lastrun,
    reportinfo.AppID,
    reportinfo.AppName,
    reportinfo.Active,
    reportinfo.LastAccessDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        ReportLog.ReportName,
        MAX(ReportLog.RunDateTime) AS lastrun,
        App.AppName,
        App.Active,
        App.AppID,
        App.LastAccessDate
    FROM ReportLog
    INNER JOIN App ON App.AppID = ReportLog.AppFk
    WHERE RIGHT(ReportLog.ReportName, 4) = '.rpt'
    GROUP BY ReportLog.ReportName, App.AppName, App.Active, App.AppID, App.LastAccessDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        App.AppPath AS ReportName,
        MAX(ReportSchedule.lastrun) AS lastrun,
        App.AppName,
        App.Active,
        App.AppID,
        App.LastAccessDate
    FROM ReportSchedule
    INNER JOIN App ON App.AppID = ReportSchedule.AppFk
    GROUP BY App.AppPath, App.AppName, App.Active, App.AppID, App.LastAccessDate
) AS reportinfo
WHERE reportinfo.lastrun < @ThresholdDate
GROUP BY
    reportinfo.ReportName,
    reportinfo.AppID,
    reportinfo.AppName,
    reportinfo.Active,
    reportinfo.LastAccessDate
ORDER BY lastrun DESC;


I've had records come back such as



ReportName
lastrun
AppID
AppName
Active
LastAccessDate




Report123
2021-09-17
123
Report123
1
2024-09-18



The LastAccessDate is accurate, and when I run SELECT MAX(RunDateTime) FROM ReportLog, I typically get a RunDateTime that matches the LastAccessDate. For example, in the case of Report123, the correct MAX(RunDateTime) should have been 2024-09-18. I could compare the RunDateTime with the LastAccessDate, but there are edge cases where the LastAccessDate doesn’t get updated, so that approach won't work consistently.
I'd appreciate any pointers I can receive.

I don't get it in the question there are 3 ways and 2 tables app and reportlog where dates of interest are recorded so where does reportschedule come into it? Also lastaccessdate always comes from app? Sample data would help clarify.

should have been no it shouldn't because WHERE reportinfo.lastrun < @ThresholdDate explicitly discards that date. If you want that date, use <=. There doesn't seem to be any problem.

You are filtering for lastrun < @ThresholdDate with @ThresholdDate = '2024-09-18'. That will exclude a 2024-09-18 date, while allowing a 2024-09-17 date.
Also, your condition is applied in a WHERE clause before the outer GROUP BY operation is performed. If your two inner data sources are producing two rows - one with a 2021-09-17 date and one with a 2021-09-18 date (with all other columns equal), one would pass and one would be filtered out. This would explain your current results.
To fix the first issue, I believe you need to use the condition lastrun <= @ThresholdDate or (if you need to handle date/time values) lastrun < DATEADD(day, 1, @ThresholdDate). For the second issue, you can move the condition from the WHERE clause to a HAVING clause, so that it executes after the outer GROUP BY operation. That would also require that you change the lastrun reference to MAX(reportinfo.lastrun).
SELECT ...
FROM (
   ...
) AS reportinfo
GROUP BY
    reportinfo.ReportName,
    reportinfo.AppID,
    reportinfo.AppName,
    reportinfo.Active,
    reportinfo.LastAccessDate
HAVING MAX(reportinfo.lastrun) <= @ThresholdDate
--HAVING MAX(reportinfo.lastrun) < DATEADD(day, 1, @ThresholdDate) -- Alternate
ORDER BY lastrun DESC;

One more thought: Do you really want to group-by LastAccessDate or should you be calculating MAX(LastAccessDate) from your data? The Active flag might also be an issue, if that value changes over time.
